# Why does my nexus 6p goes black after call is answered

Tags: calls

when I make or recieve a call as soon as I click the call or answer button the screen goes black. And I can't hear anything thru the ear speaker. However, when I put it on speaker it stays normal. What can cause this issue?

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: Do ear speakers usually work on that device at all? Maybe it is a hardware issue, and they are simply broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has an hardware issue. The [proximity sensor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_sensor) is broken or is covered.

But before, did you put a screen protector, such as tempered glass, may it doesn't have  proper cutouts.

As a workaround, I'd suggest you set up the power button to end calls **(Settings -> Accessibility -> Power button ends call).**

You should consider taking the phone to a repair center if the above don't work.